# Combining dashboard report of multiple projects in maven

Tags: jenkins, maven-2, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am using mvn dashboard plugin to create the dashboard of surefire and cobertura test reports. I have 2 projects and it is creating two different dashboards for two different projects. How i can combine these two dashboard report into one in maven.

This is required as i am using jenkins to execute my two projects independently and create report for me !!